# Fused Location Not returning location when GPS turned on

Tags: android, gps, location

We have a requirement to get user location with different intervals. I am using Fused Location API recommended by google to fetch user location. Application wants to get user location in both mode whether internet available or not. we are getting user location warning him to enable his/her GPS always to get his/her location.

1. if user have WiFi and GPS active i am getting location its fine.
2. if user have GPS active only again i am getting location. but sometime i am getting location with very higher accuracy like 1000 meter
3. but if user turned off his GPS for a while and turn it on again.
   Then after turning on GPS Fused Location unable to get location
   until i open google map or connect to internet.

> Following are my devices

> ```
>  1. Galaxy Samsung S4 os 5.1
>  2. Realme 7Pro os 10
> ```
>
> This Question is asked on multiple threads but still i am unable to
> get my answer
>
> I have read Fused Location Documentation and stack overflow answer which says cache cleared when user turned of GPS and when you open turn on GPS again there should be one client should be connected to get location.

***but my real concern is how i can get my location without going to
google map or activating my internet. IS there any option to minimize accuracy in point 2 and how i can get location in case 3 ( real headache )***

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    var REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100

    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 999
        const val TAG = "MainActivity"
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        


        button.setOnClickListener {

            latTextView.text = "0.0"
            lngTextView.text = "0.0"
            accuracy.text = "0.0"

            when {
                PermissionUtils.isAccessFineLocationGranted(this) -> {
                    when {
                        PermissionUtils.isLocationEnabled(this) -> {
                            if (::fusedLocationProviderClient.isInitialized) {
                                removeLocationUpdates(true)
                            } else {
                                setUpLocationListener()
                            }
                        }
                        else -> {
                            PermissionUtils.showGPSNotEnabledDialog(this)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    PermissionUtils.requestAccessFineLocationPermission(
                        this,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun removeLocationUpdates(isStartLocation: Boolean) {
        var result = fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallBack)
        result.addOnCompleteListener {
            Log.e(TAG, "request removed")
            if (isStartLocation) {
                setUpLocationListener()
            }

        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun setUpLocationListener(priority: Int = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY) {


        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        // for getting the current location update after every 2 seconds with high accuracy
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        locationRequest.interval = 4000
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 1000
        locationRequest.priority = priority

        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)//.setAlwaysShow(true)
        val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this)
        val task: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.e(TAG, "task success")
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest,
                locationCallBack,
                Looper.myLooper()
            )
        }

        task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e(TAG, "task exception")
            if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    exception.startResolutionForResult(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS
                    )
                } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
            }
        }


      
    }

    var locationCallBack = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult)

            Log.e(TAG, "Locations found : ${locationResult.locations.size}")

            removeLocationUpdates(false)

            for (location in locationResult.locations) {

                Log.e(TAG, " Location time is : ${location.time}")

                latTextView.text = location.latitude.toString()
                lngTextView.text = location.longitude.toString()
                accuracy.text = location.accuracy.toString()
            }
            // Few more things we can do here:
            // For example: Update the location of user on server
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onLocationAvailability(p0: LocationAvailability?) {
            super.onLocationAvailability(p0)
            Log.e(TAG, "Location result is ${p0}")

            availability.text = p0?.isLocationAvailable?.toString()


        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    when {
                        PermissionUtils.isLocationEnabled(this) -> {
                            setUpLocationListener()
                        }
                        else -> {
                            PermissionUtils.showGPSNotEnabledDialog(this)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        getString(R.string.location_permission_not_granted),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

PermissionUtils.kt

```
object PermissionUtils {
    /**
     * Function to request permission from the user
     */
    fun requestAccessFineLocationPermission(activity: AppCompatActivity, requestId: Int) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            requestId
        )
    }

    /**
     * Function to check if the location permissions are granted or not
     */
    fun isAccessFineLocationGranted(context: Context): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    /**
     * Function to check if location of the device is enabled or not
     */
    fun isLocationEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    }

    /**
     * Function to show the "enable GPS" Dialog box
     */
    fun showGPSNotEnabledDialog(context: Context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.enable_gps))
            .setMessage(context.getString(R.string.required_for_this_app))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.enable_now)) { _, _ ->
                context.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
            }
            .show()
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.location">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.location"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
```

activity_mail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/availability"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/default_lat"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />


    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fetch Location"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/default_lat"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lngTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/default_lng"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accuracy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Related: [Android location is inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14183849/295004) Answer to that question still holds. GPS by itself takes a while to get a location fix.

Comment: @MorrisonChang i waited for one whole day to get location after turning on GPS. go to main road but it did not get location until i turned on wifi

Comment: FusedLocationProvider, to my understanding is battery optimized, was the device in hand and/or not in sleep/doze mode at any time? Also assuming you have a clear view of the sky.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes i was under clear view of sky. device was not in doze mode. as actually i was trying to get location around 10 minutes

Comment: Did you try `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` when running your GPS on / WiFi off test?

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes i tried with this. on Realme 7pro sometime i got location with low or high accuracy but on samsung s3 it did not do any thing. inside room it do not work on both. but on open sky it works on realme 7pro 2 out 10 times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227628/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-rizwan-rasheed).

Comment: Any solution? I am also facing the same problem @RizwanRasheed

Comment: @farhan no solution.